# Highcharts - more series then data

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I searched the StackVlow, but couldn't find a solution to the following problem.
I build the series of the column chart in a loop which is given by an map. Basically everything works fine. But I always see a series that is too much.

[image]

The picture shows that I actually have five series, which are shown correctly for the column. But there is also a series 6 in the legend. At first I thought the map had empty values, but the map looks like this.

[image]

and the assignment to the chart series looks like this.

```
  map.forEach((value, key) => {
    this.resultChart.addSeries({
                                 type: 'column',
                                 name: key.replace('_', ' '),
                                 data: value,
                                 color: DisplayUtil.getStatusColor(key)
                               });
  });
```

So the question is where does this series come from?
If I delete the data from the database so that the map is empty, this series is still there.

```
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    if (this.chartData) {
      this.chartData.forEach((item) => {
        this.categories.push(this.getWeekNumber(item.historyDate));
      });

      const chartOptions: Options = this.createDefaultColumnOptions();
      chartOptions.title.text = this.chartTitle;
      this.resultChart = Highcharts.chart(this.resultChartTarget.nativeElement, chartOptions);
      this.resultChart.addSeries(this.buildColumnSeries(this.chartData));
    }
  }
```

Here is the method how the series are built.

```
private buildColumnSeries(chartData: any[]) {
    const options: SeriesOptions = {
      id: this.uuidService.getNewUuid(),
    } as SeriesOptions;

    if (chartData.length > 0) {
      const map = new Map();

      chartData.forEach((item) => {
        const chartDataStatus = item[this.statusLabel];
        const keys = Object.keys(chartDataStatus);
        keys.forEach((key) => {
          if (this.keyExist(map, key)) {
            const array = map.get(key);
            array.push(chartDataStatus[key]);
            map.set(key, array);
          } else {
            map.set(key, [chartDataStatus[key]]);
          }
        });
      });

      console.log("map: ", map);

      map.forEach((value, key) => {
        this.resultChart.addSeries({
                                     type: 'column',
                                     name: key.replace('_', ' '),
                                     data: value,
                                     color: DisplayUtil.getStatusColor(key)
                                   });
      });
    }

    return options;
  }
```

Anyone have any idea where this Series 6 is coming from?

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue on some online editor that I could work on?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-http-pzt3s?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:636-1054
Dates here look good. The only difference is that I gave the data manually, from line 22 till 43.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning a series option in the Option build ColumnSeries method is not necessary and causes a problem with the data series. The chart options have already been defined a few lines above:

```
const chartOptions: Options = this.createDefaultColumnOptions ();
```

The changed method looks like this now.

```
private buildColumnSeries(cData: StatisticsHistoryModel[]) {
    if (cData.length > 0) {
      const map = new Map();
      cData.forEach((item) => {
        const chartDataStatus = item[this.statusLabel];
        const keys = Object.keys(chartDataStatus);
        keys.forEach((key) => {
          if (this.keyExist(map, key)) {
            const array = map.get(key);
            array.push(chartDataStatus[key]);
            map.set(key, array);
          } else {
            map.set(key, [chartDataStatus[key]]);
          }
        });
      });

      map.forEach((value, key) => {
        this.resultChart.addSeries({
                                     type: 'column',
                                     name: key.replace('_', ' '),
                                     data: value,
                                     color: DisplayUtil.getStatusColor(key)
                                   });
      });
    }
  }
```